# FreeTDS - tsql connects, isql fails

Tags: sql-server, ruby, linux, freetds, isql

I'm trying to connect to a database on my host machine (windows xp, sql server 05).  My guest machine is Ubuntu 10.04.  I can connect and execute commands with tsql, but isql fails. Below are my config files and error messages.

freetds.conf

```
text size = 64512

[SQLEXPRESS]
host = 192.168.163.1
port = 1433
tds version = 7.0
```

odbcinst.ini

```
[FreeTDS]
Description     = TDS driver (Sybase/MS SQL)
Driver          = /usr/lib/odbc/libtdsodbc.so
Setup           = /usr/lib/odbc/libtdsS.so
CPTimeout       =
CPReuse         =
FileUsage       = 1
```

odbc.ini

```
[SQLEXPRESS]
Driver          = FreeTDS
Description     = ODBC connection via FreeTDS
Trace           = No
Servername  = 192.168.163.1
Database        = SCOPE_Peel
Port        = 1433
UID         = sa
PWD         = test1234
ReadOnly    = No
```

tsql:

```
tsql -S SQLEXPRESS  -U sa
#success
```

isql:

```
isql SQLEXPRESS sa test1234 -v
[S1000][unixODBC][FreeTDS][SQL Server]Unable to connect to data source
[ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLConnect
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue was this line in odbc.ini

`Servername  = 192.168.163.1`

It should have been SQLEXPRESS which I think points to the name of the server configured in freetds.conf

Comment: Hello, i have set the same Servername as SQLEXPRESS but still i am getting the same error.