# freeTDS not using its config

Tags: sql-server, linux, ubuntu-10.04, freetds

I've decided to use FreeTDS driver and unixODBC to manage the PDO connection between my LAMP-based app with a remote MsSQL database.
unfortunately it appears that the driver doesn't read the freetds.conf file, nor the environmental variables set either directly via server's CLI or specified in php file by putenv() function.

now some data:

1. as I ping the server - no packets are lost.
2. as I telnet the server on 1433 port - the connection is established
3. as I use the command

   ```
   TDSVER=7.0 tsql -H >IP< -p 1433 -U username
   ```

   I am prompted to enter password and connection is established.
4. without the TDSVER preceding the command - the connection fails with such a message:

   ```
   Error 20017 (severity 9):
       Unexpected EOF from the server
       OS error 115, "Operation now in progress"
   Error 20002 (severity 9):
       Adaptive Server connection failed
   There was a problem connecting to the server
   ```
5. the tsql -C commands echos such an output:

   ```
   Compile-time settings (established with the "configure" script)
                          Version: freetds v0.91
           freetds.conf directory: /usr/local/etc
   MS db-lib source compatibility: yes
      Sybase binary compatibility: no
                    Thread safety: yes
                    iconv library: yes
                      TDS version: 5.0
                            iODBC: no
                         unixodbc: yes
            SSPI "trusted" logins: no
                         Kerberos: no
   ```
6. freetds.conf in the location given above has this entry:

   ```
   [MSSQL]
   host = >IP<
   port = 1433
   tds version = 7.0
   ```
7. the ISQL also fails:

   ```
   isql -v MSSQL
   [S1000][unixODBC][FreeTDS][SQL Server]Unable to connect to data source
   [01000][unixODBC][FreeTDS][SQL Server]Adaptive Server connection failed
   [ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLConnect
   ```
8. my odbc.ini :

   ```
   [MSSQL]
   Description = MS SQL Server
   Driver = FreeTDS
   TDS_Version = 7.0
   Server = >IP<
   UID = username
   PWD = password
   ReadOnly = No
   Port = 1433
   ```

I suppose the solution is really simple, but i'm just too stupid to find it...

Comment: I found this question via ddg: "freetds linux not working," and my problem was I did not have the port specifically defined.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I spent a long time today debugging a similar problem. I had set "TDS version" in freetds.conf but it was not being used in my ODBC connection. After reading the freetds source code (connectparams.c:odbc_parse_connect_string) I discovered that:

- If your connection string uses "SERVER=" then both freetds.conf and odbc.ini are ignored
- If your connection string uses "SERVERNAME=" then the settings in the appropriate freetds.conf server are used
- If your connection string uses "DSN=" then the settings in the appropriate odbc.ini DSN are used

odbcinst.ini is a red herring. FreeTDS never checks that for settings.

The settings you specify *in the connection string* are always respected. It also always respects the environment variables like TDSVER.

Comment: Thanks for the research: it confirms what I was bashing my head against just now: `DBI:ODBC` not reading `/etc/freetds/freetds.conf` when I'm using the `Server=` parameter in my DSN-less connection string (and `strings /usr/lib/odbc/libtdsodbc.so|grep conf` showing the library knows where to locate the config file. Running `strace ... -e open ...` also confirmed no `freetds.conf` is attempted to be read.

Comment: And example 4.3 [here](http://freetds.schemamania.org/userguide/dsnless.htm) confirms your research. Thanks again.

Comment: If I try to connect via PHP with SERVERNAME=... then I get the error: "SQLSTATE[08001] SQLDriverConnect: 0 [unixODBC][FreeTDS][SQL Server]Unable to connect to data source"

It only works with SERVER=...

Any idea why?

Comment: @kinske I get the same error with `SERVERNAME`, while `SERVER` works.

Comment: I am connecting with `HOST=xx.xx.xx.xx` and needed a `putenv("TDSVER=8.0");` in my PHP code before connect.

Answer (score 9):

My gut instinct is you need to change your **tds version = 7.0** to **tds version = 8.0** in your freetds.conf and odbc.ini files AND you need something in your odbcinst.ini file. Here's what I've got working on an Ubuntu 12.04 server talking to a remote MSSQL server:

freetds.conf

```
# Define a connection to the MSSQL server.
[mssql]
    host = myserver
    port = 1433
    tds version = 8.0
```

odbc.ini

```
# Define a connection to the MSSQL server.
# The Description can be whatever we want it to be.
# The Driver value must match what we have defined in /etc/odbcinst.ini
# The Database name must be the name of the database this connection will connect to.
# The ServerName is the name we defined in /etc/freetds/freetds.conf
# The TDS_Version should match what we defined in /etc/freetds/freetds.conf
[mssql]
Description             = MSSQL Server
Driver                  = freetds
Database                = MyDB
ServerName              = myserver
TDS_Version             = 8.0
```

odbcinst.ini

```
# Define where to find the driver for the Free TDS connections.
[freetds]
Description     = MS SQL database access with Free TDS
Driver          = /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsodbc.so
Setup           = /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsS.so
UsageCount      = 1
```

Comment: thanks a lot man, i will try to apply your suggestions as i will be @ work tomorrow

Comment: i just copied this  on centos 6 64bit. it does not work

Comment: Anyone have any ideas where to get MSSQL drivers for Mac OS X for FreeTDS?

Answer (score 5):

I experienced this exact same problem, but my config was already correctly set up. The problem was that the TDS versions that freetds.conf recognizes has changed in newer versions, but apparently the old versions still work in the TDSVER environment variable. Once I set the version in the config files to 7.1 rather than 8.0 everything started working.

Comment: WORKED FOR ME! Thanks.  After hours of testing and googling I couldn't believe this is all that it took to get the system up and running.

Comment: I debugged my setup thru `export TDSDUMP=/temp/freetds.log` in `~/.bashrc`, which made it clear that the tds version was not being set by the config file. Once I set the environment variable `export TDSVER=8.0` everything worked.

Answer (score 1):

The initial `TDSVER=7.0` issue was resolved by adding the following at the end of my `odbc.ini` file:

```
[Default]
Driver=/usr/local/lib/libtdsodbc.so
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of connecting to an IP, try to connect to the name of the configuration section?  For example:

```
isql -v MSSQL
```

Comment: Do you also have an `odbc.ini` ?  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8010361/freetds-tsql-connects-isql-fails

Comment: Try to change `Server = 10.2.201.2` in `odbc.ini` to `Server = MSSQL` ?

Comment: i'm pretty sure the reason for that behaviour is in the fact that FreeTDS doesn't use TDSVER=7.0, which is required for Microsoft's SQL Servers

Comment: Try to change `TDS_Version` to `TDS Version`?  Though it should have picked that up from the tds config file

Comment: yes it should, i changed, but the result is the same as before.