# sql server login (windows authentication account) from linux client through isql utility

Tags: sql-server, linux, authentication, windows-authentication, unixodbc

I am trying to connect to SQL Server running on Windows from a Redhat machine. I can login to the server through the "SQL Server" account but not from a "Windows Authentication" account. I tried all sorts of tricks - but none worked:

```
# isql FBI_MS CORP\\Kapilv kapil
# isql FBI_MS 192.168.14.158\\CORP\\Kapilv kapil
# isql FBI_MS 'CORP\Kapilv' kapil
```

I also googled and came across: https://askubuntu.com/questions/167491/connecting-ms-sql-using-freetds-and-unixodbc-isql-no-default-driver-specified

I have unixODBC drivers but do not have freetds. I should still be able to connect without freetds. Or is it impossible to connect with just unixODBC drivers?

-- I installed freetds as suggested by Benny Hill and followed the configurations - I could still not get it to work.

odbc.ini:

```
[FBI_MSW]
Description = FBI MS SQL Server database using freetds
Driver = freetds
Database = FBI
ServerName = 192.168.14.158
TDS_Version = 8.0
```

odbcinst.ini (RedHat installation of freetds does not come with a `Set Up` file

```
[freetds]
Description = MS SQL database access with Free TDS
Driver = /usr/local/freetds/lib/libtdsodbc.so
Setup =
TraceFile = /tmp/freetds.log
FileUsage = 1
UsageCount = 1
```

Now, when I try to connect - I get the following error messages:

```
[root@localhost sqlncli-11.0.1790.0]# isql -v FBI_MSW CORP\\Kapilv kapil
[S1000][unixODBC][FreeTDS][SQL Server]Unable to connect to data source
[01000][unixODBC][FreeTDS][SQL Server]Unknown host machine name.
[ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLConnect
```

I cannot even connect to `SQL Server` account through freetds (which i could without freetds) - what can i say about `Windows Authentication` account?

Answer (score 0):

What is the error message you got?

It is better to be sure, if you can reach the MS SQL server, so try: `telnet 192.168.14.158 1433` (or the port it is running on)

Comment: There are no connectivity issues. I can connect to MS SQL server through port 1433 with a SQL-Server account but cannot connect through Windows-authentication. I have enabled both modes of login access in the properties.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to install FreeTDS.

Look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13066716/freetds-not-using-its-config/13069820#13069820) and the answer I submitted there to see configuration examples.