# How to enable pdo_odbc on Homestead

Tags: php, ubuntu, laravel, odbc, homestead

I've just booted up a homestead VM and want to connect to an advantage database, i need to use an odbc connection. With XAMPP i just edited php.ini

```
extension=php_pdo_odbc.dll
```

but on my homestead box I can't see how to enable it. Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

Thanks

Comment: Firstly you have to login to your homstead using ssh. And try to edit your homestead's `php.ini`.

Comment: Which line do I edit? I've uncommented some lines but they've had no effect.

Comment: Try to edit `php.ini` with `sudo` and try to restart your server. read installation on [php doc](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.installation.php).

Comment: Could also use sudo php5enmod php_pdo_odbc

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not that you are using Homestead. The problem is that ODBC is for the Windows platform, instead of Linux.

Looking into questions relating PDO+OSBC and Linux might help you find a way.

[Connect PHP to MSSQL via PDO ODBC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20163776/connect-php-to-mssql-via-pdo-odbc)