# Error connecting to SQL Server with php-71w using PDO dblib

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

I've been trying to connect to a SQL Server Express instance using php 7.1 from webtatic.

Here are things I have tried

```
$DBH = new PDO("dblib:host=10.10.0.81:1434;dbname=database_name", "username", "password")

$DBH = new PDO("dblib:host=10.10.0.81,1434;dbname=database_name", "username", "password")

$DBH = new PDO("dblib:host=10.10.0.81\SQLEXPRESS:1434;dbname=database_name", "username", "password")

$DBH = new PDO("dblib:host=10.10.0.81:1434\SQLEXPRESS;dbname=database_name", "username", "password")

$DBH = new PDO("dblib:host=10.10.0.81,1434;dbname=database_name", "username", "password")
```

And many others. The error I always get is "Unknown host machine name"
I have tried connecting with the IP and with the hostname and neither work. I can ping the IP just fine and there isn't a firewall blocking the port.

It is using a SQL Server instance and we manually assigned the IP 1434. I was able to verify it is working with a 3rd party client.

Comment: An idea: prepend `//` to the ip.

Comment: Nope, same error

Comment: Haven't used it but it's my understanding that Linux-based MSSQL PDO is done through FreeTDS. Have you configured that at all?

Comment: @miken32 , it would show "Driver not found" error or something similar if he hadn't done it.

Comment: Try the suggestion in the first answer of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29570235/php-dblib-error-sqlstatehy000-unknown-host-machine-name-severity-2