# MSSQL Parameterized Queries

Tags: php, sql-server, database

Over MySQLi I would do:

```
$sql = $connect->prepare("INSERT INTO Table (a, b) VALUES (?, ?)");
$sql->bind_param('ss', $a, $b);
$sql->execute();
$sql->close();
```

Now the question is, how I do the same thing with mssql for a SQL Server instead of MySQL?

I know I could do:

```
$sql = sqlsrv_query($connect, "INSERT INTO Table (a, b) VALUES (?, ?)", array($a, $b));
```

However, this requires the SQL Drivers specific for windows, which I cannot use over a linux platform (where in fact my website is hosted).

My server has however the mssql library installed, and even if it's deprecated, still it work pretty good with PHP 5.6

I have troubles on parameterizing the queries though, all I could do is:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO Table (a, b) VALUES ('$a', '$b')";
mssql_query($sql, $connect);
```

But of course I do not want to directly insert the values, so how I can parameterize that query on mssql?

Answer (score 0):

Seems that this is not of the most easiest things to do. Anyway definitely prepared statements will happen with [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php)

From original PHP docs:

> If it is not possible to use SqlSrv, you can use the [PDO_ODBC](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-odbc.php) driver
>   to connect to Microsoft SQL Server and Sybase databases, as the native
>   Windows DB-LIB is ancient, thread un-safe and no longer supported by
>   Microsoft.

You can read **PDO_ODBC on UNIX systems** section for your case. Don't forget to read **comments** too, they might be useful for you to understand how should this happen.

You can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20163776/connect-php-to-mssql-via-pdo-odbc) stack overflow question.

And this is how you make parameterized query with PDO:

```
$sql = 'SELECT name, colour, calories FROM fruit
    WHERE calories < :calories AND colour = :colour';
// where $dbh is PDO object
$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql, array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_FWDONLY));
$sth->execute(array(':calories' => 150, ':colour' => 'red'));
$red = $sth->fetchAll();
$sth->execute(array(':calories' => 175, ':colour' => 'yellow'));
$yellow = $sth->fetchAll();
```

see other examples on [official docs](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php).

Good luck friend and don't forget to share your experience.