# PHP Laravel Adaptive Server connection failed (severity 9)

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to use MsSQL with my Laravel project. But when I execute the select query.

> [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]   SQLSTATE[01002] Adaptive Server
>   connection failed (severity 9) (SQL: exec sp_EntityFullList)
>
> [Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException]   SQLSTATE[01002] Adaptive
>   Server connection failed (severity 9)
>
> [PDOException]   SQLSTATE[01002] Adaptive Server connection failed
>   (severity 9)

```
$db = DB::connection('sqlsrv');
        print_r($db->select('exec sp_EntityFullList')->disableQueryLog());
```

Also I can connect the database with this command in cli.

TDSVER=8.0 tsql -H ip  -U username -p 1433 -P pass

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20163776/connect-php-to-mssql-via-pdo-odbc

Comment: I applied this steps but result is same

Comment: Any Suggestion or help about this ?