# Connecting to remote SQL Server through PHP on CentOS 7

Tags: php, sql-server, odbc, freetds

I have followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20163776/connect-php-to-mssql-via-pdo-odbc) solution for what seems to be the exact same problem, however I am not having as much success as I had hoped. 
I set up the required config files for PDO_ODBC, unixODBC and FreeTDS packages:

1. First by specifiying the host in `/etc/freetds.conf` :

   ```
   [mssql]
   host = DBHost
   port = 1433
   tds version = 7.3
   ```
2. Then by specifying the FreeTDS driver location in `/etc/odbcinst.ini` :

   ```
   [freetds]
   Description = Ms SQL database access with Free TDS
   Driver64 = /usr/lib64/libtdsodbc.so.0
   Setup64 = /usr/lib64/libtdsS.so.2
   FileUsage = 1
   UsageCount = 1
   ```
3. Then by specifying the DSN in `/etc/odbc.ini` :

   ```
   [mssql]
   Description = mssql server
   Driver = FreeTDS
   Database = CET_PhonesDB
   ServerName = mssql
   TDS_Version = 7.3
   ```

Finally here is my PHP:

```
 try {
        $pdo = new PDO('odbc:mssql', 'dbuser', 'dbpass');
 }
 catch(Exception $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
 }
```

which returns: "SQLSTATE[08S01] SQLConnect: 20009 [unixODBC][FreeTDS][SQL Server]Unable to connect: Adaptive Server is unavailable or does not exist".

I've tried troubleshooting using `$tsql -S mssql -U dbuser -P dbpass` (which tests the FreeTDS) and `$isql mssql dbuser dbpass` (Which tests the unixODBC) both of which connect successfully. This leads me to believe that the problem is with PDO_ODBC or something else in the PHP configuration. Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I narrowed the problem down to the Apache server, by running my PHP script through the command line: `$php /var/www/html/repo/index.php` and the connection was made succesfully.

A coworker suggested that SELinux could be interfering with httpd, and sure enough running `$setenforce 0` allowed my PHP to run properly when requesting them through a web browser.

Since disabling SELinux permenantly is a ***VERY BAD*** idea, I did some fiddling and digging and thanks to [this](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/SELinux/apache) manual I found that `$sudo setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1` allows scripts that the Apache runs to create network connections of their own. And now SELinux should let any PHP script executed by httpd create network connections.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it by using a custom port: port = XXXXX in freetds.conf. This port should be configured in SQL Server Configuration Mgnt
SQL Server Network Configuration -> TCP/IP (enabled) -> IP Addresses -> IPAll -> TCP Dynamic Ports
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177440.aspx