# configure pdo_dblib - freetds already installed

Tags: php, pdo, freetds

I am running a Linux server that already has freetds installed, but is not configured to support dblib. Only sqlite and mysql are currently supported for PDO. MSSQL support is also enabled.

If I want to add support for dblib and enable the PDO Driver for FreeTDS/Sybase DB-lib, do I just need to run this command on the existing install:

```
 ./configure --with-pdo-dblib
```

If so, from which directory would I run the command?

Environment:
PHP Version 5.5.38
CENTOS 6.9

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you have configured `FreeTDS` correctly, you should be able to connect like so:

```
$pdo = new PDO("dblib:host=mssql;dbname=$dbname", "$dbuser","$dbpwd");
```

If you can't, this answer gives more explicit instructions: [Connect PHP to MSSQL via PDO ODBC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20163776/connect-php-to-mssql-via-pdo-odbc)

`pdo_dblib` is typically installed in most Linux distros when you install `php-mssql` (on CentOS and Ubuntu, for example). If the connect command isn't working, please rewrite your question to include the specific steps you have taken and the error output. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you. Actually making a connection to the database is not an issue though, I can do that on our internal server that is configured with PDO ODBC.  But on the server in question, it was not installed for some reason. My issue is adding / activating that driver. But since asking this question, support at the hosting company has added the driver.

Answer (score 0):

Since writing this question, the support team at the company that is hosting this server installed the driver. I don't know exactly what steps they took to do it so I can not post a step by step answer as I would like. Closing this question.