# How to connect xampp php 7.1.27 to a MsSQL server using pdo?

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

I'm trying to connect to a MsSQL server database with php pdo, but I get this error:

> Could not find driver.

I've tried all solutions on stackoverflow none of them worked.

- Installed php driver and configured php.ini. added these one by one:

  extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_71_ts.dll

  extension=php_sqlsrv_71_ts.dll

  extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_71_nts.dll

  and all of them at once.
- Used the pdo_dblib_mssql class: https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-dblib.php.
- Used different PDO constructors:

```
$conn = new PDO ("dblib:host=$hostname:$port;dbname=dbname","username","pwd");
```

and

```
$conn = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=$servername;Database=dbname", "username", "pwd");
```

Nothing worked, any help would be appreciated.

PHP version : 7.1.27 / MsSQL SERVER 2014.

Comment: Do you find `sqlsrv` in the ouput from `<?php phpinfo();?>`?

Comment: Or check [getAvailableDrivers()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.getavailabledrivers.php). Also think about using [ODBC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20163776/connect-php-to-mssql-via-pdo-odbc?answertab=active#tab-top).

Comment: @Zhorov no there's sqlsrv in phpinfo

Comment: @aladdin Then, PHP driver for SQL Server is not loaded. You need to install appropriate ODBC Driver.

Comment: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=50420

Comment: I will install odbc driver now and check if it works thank you.

Comment: I tried ODBC it worked, thank you guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer from the comments:

- Download and install [ODBC Driver](http://microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=50420)
- Configure php.ini file by uncommenting this line:
  `extension=php_odbc.dll`
- Restart xampp
- use this method to connect :

```
odbc_connect ( "Driver={SQL Server};Server=$servername;Database=$dbname" , $username ,  $password);
```