# freetds version isn't changing, while file is changed

Tags: sql-server, linux, unicode, freetds

I have a freetds installation at my linux machine

when i check the tds version using tsql -C

```
Compile-time settings (established with the "configure" script)
                            Version: freetds v0.91
             freetds.conf directory: /etc
     MS db-lib source compatibility: yes
        Sybase binary compatibility: yes
                      Thread safety: yes
                      iconv library: yes
                        TDS version: 4.2
                              iODBC: no
                           unixodbc: yes
              SSPI "trusted" logins: no
                           Kerberos: yes
```

however in my /etc/freetds.conf i have set the TDS Version to 8.0

```
[global]
        # TDS protocol version
#       tds version = 8.0

        # Whether to write a TDSDUMP file for diagnostic purposes
        # (setting this to /tmp is insecure on a multi-user system)
#       dump file = /tmp/freetds.log
#       debug flags = 0xffff
        tds version = 8.0
        port = 1433
        client charset = UTF-8
        debug flags = 0x4fff
        timeout = 180
        connect timeout = 180
        text size = 20971520
```

I really need it to be set to 8.0, because I am facing this issue while running my sql queries from a linux end point 
"Unicode data in a Unicode-only collation or ntext data cannot be sent to clients using DB-Library"
And one of the only fixes i see suitable is to mark the tds version as 8.0 and set the charset to UTF-8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have also changed the tds version at the odbc.ini file with param
TDS_Version = 8.0

I took a cue from here [freeTDS not using its config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13066716/freetds-not-using-its-config?rq=1)